# Can someone help me troubleshoot PC shutdown (I have HWmonitor logs in spreadsheet)

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, gpu, troubleshooting

Happens when heavily gaming, PC will suddenly power down without warning.  I can't boot it back up unless I unplug the PSU from the wall and back in, then it comes up fine.

I've run HW monitor logging sensors to disk to try to catch it in the act, and here's my results from the last time it happened, sorted by most recent first.  Oddly enough, I see some spikes, but it's in the second from most recent.  Maybe a surge, and it went back down, a second before the PC reacted and powered down?

From looking at it, no temps look insane to me, so it doesn't seem to be a thermal issue.  Several procs under heavy load and the power (highlighted) surged, but I don't know if that's in normal range or what.

Any thoughts?

Details:

- Ryzen 3800x
- 32GB DDR 4
- Asus TUF x570 mobo
- Corsair CX750 PSU
- GTX 3080 GPU

The entire build is relatively new, but the GPU is the latest addition.  This didn't happen before the GPU, but I only had the rest together a month or so before the GPU arrived, and didn't push it hard.

[HW Monitor Logs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CZcUoE7lFijtTuq-VzynVYJHxe4yTJU6VIrBd463pu4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: you might consider a PSU upgrade, 750W is the minimum for a 3080, sounds like the PSU is tripping and needs a hard reset by unplugging the power to work again.